# Issues with understanding Javascript yarn pattern program

Tags: javascript

I came across the Javascript YarnPattern program from Stanford's CS106AX. However, as I was going through the code, I have difficulty understanding some lines.

In the main function YarnPattern(), I don't quite understand the bold chunk written between the stars " ** ". I'm not quite sure what it means when the variables are initialised with thisPeg = 0 and nextPeg = -1.

Also, I'm not quite sure about the line "nextPeg = (thisPeg + DELTA) % pegs.length". I was wondering how this line of code can help reaching a suitable peg's index position.

It would be great if someone can provide a clear explanation with regards to these lines of code. Your help is much appreciated.

```
// Constants 
const GWINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;
const GWINDOW_HEIGHT = 625;
const N_ACROSS = 80;
const N_DOWN = 50;
const DELTA = 113;

// main function 
function YarnPattern() {
  let gw = GWindow(GWINDOW_WIDTH, GWINDOW_HEIGHT);
  let pegs = createPegArray(GWINDOW_WIDTH, GWINDOW_HEIGHT, N_ACROSS, N_DOWN);
  **let thisPeg = 0;
  let nextPeg = -1;
  while (thisPeg !== 0 || nextPeg === -1) {
    nextPeg = (thisPeg + DELTA) % pegs.length;
    let p0 = pegs[thisPeg];
    let p1 = pegs[nextPeg];
    let line = GLine(p0.x, p0.y, p1.x, p1.y);** 
    line.setColor("Magenta");
    gw.add(line);
    thisPeg = nextPeg;
  }
}

function createPegArray(width, height, nAcross, nDown) {
    let dx = width / nAcross;
    let dy = height / nDown;
    let pegs = [ ];
    for (let i = 0; i < nAcross; i++) {
      pegs.push(Point(i * dx, 0));
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < nDown; i++) {
      pegs.push(Point(nAcross * dx, i * dy));
    }
    for (let i = nAcross; i > 0; i--) {
      pegs.push(Point(i * dx, nDown * dy));
    }
    for (let i = nDown; i > 0; i--) {
      pegs.push(Point(0, i * dy));
    }
    return pegs; 
}

function Point(x, y) {
  if (x === undefined) {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
  }
  return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain what the program is doing for context?

Comment: It seems that `DELTA` is the pace and `% pegs.length` prevents overflow, for example, if `p0` is the item at index `2`, `p1` is set to the item at index `115` (`2 + DELTA`)

Comment: It is trying to create a pattern that simulates winding a piece of yarn around an array of pegs at the edges of the graphics window. It simulates the following process:
- Tie a piece of yarn around the peg in the upper left corner.
- Loop that yarn around the peg a certain distance DELTA ahead.
- Continue moving forward DELTA pegs until you close the loop.
@VLAZ

Comment: I kind of got an idea of what you're been trying to explain. Thank you so much! @Titus Would you mind explaining the part where the initialised variables are set to 0 and -1 respectively? Why is it so?

Comment: The variables are initialised to those values because of the loop's condition `thisPeg !== 0 || nextPeg === -1`. `nextPeg` can be `-1` (or any negative value) only on the first iteration and `thisPeg` will become zero after `113` (the `DELTA`) iterations (this will be the case if `DELTA` is smaller than `pegs.length` and `pegs.length` is not divisible by `DELTA`).